# Sharepoint Trip Planner - Event list and Task lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am trying to create a trip planner for my team.

One list has the list of trips, Date(s) (start and end), Location, Who is going, Task Progress, etc.

The other list has a list of tasks organized by their calculated due dates (example: these grouped tasks must be completed 30 days out, 14 days out, 7 days out, etc)

Each task has the following information:
Task progress (Not Started, ongoing, completed) where each value is calculated with an IF statement to another column  (Not started = 0, ongoing = 0.5, completed = 1)

The Progress and calculated due dates from list of tasks are what displays on the List of Trips.

What I had previously was one massive list to allow for calculations with different views to hide the "calculation" columns:

Trip | Task 1.a | Task 1.b   | Task Count |Task SUM     |Task Progress|

Title|:Choice   |:Calculated:| Calculated:|Calculated   | Calculated   |

However, I am finding is that if a task has to be removed or edited, its a process, because both columns need to be edited for all the formulas to work. For people who are not familiar with sharepoint, it is difficult. My intent is to make it easier for other people in my department to edit the list of tasks.

Eventually, there will be a form that incorporates the list of tasks when a new trip is created. Probably through a power apps relationship...?

What I need to figure out is how to retrieve the Task progress and due dates from the task list to display them on the List of trips.

Thank-you!